# get the right info in another table php

Tags: php, cross-database

guys!

I have this database *table: post

```
post_id ++++++ title  +++++++ date   ++++ category  +++++ id

10504   ++++++ Hello  +++++++ 09.28  ++++ adobe     +++++ 01 
10504   ++++++ Hi     +++++++ 09.28  ++++ photoshop +++++ 02
10505   ++++++ Dexter +++++++ 09.29  ++++ series    +++++ 03
```

Where post_id is the id from author (who write the post)

And I have this database *table: author

```
  post_id ++++++ name   +++++++ pass   ++++ avatar    +++++ id

  10504   ++++++ John   +++++++ admin  ++++ admin.png +++++ 69
  10505   ++++++ Dexter +++++++ dex00  ++++ dex00.png +++++ 70
```

My page is like:

```
         <?php do { ?>
         // div content //
         echo $row_post['title'];
         echo $row_post['date'];
         echo $row_post['category'];
         <img src="<?php echo $row_post['avatar']; ?>"
        // end div content //
        <?php } while ($row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post)); ?>
```

With this code above,I can get all posts that I have in "post" database.This is working great.
But I can't get the avatar from who wrote the post. How I can do this ?

CHECKLIST:

•I tried ( if ) function,but isn't work for me.
•I tried create a session with the id_post,but show only the last or the first avatar in database.

I need something like:

if (post) post_id = (author) post_id show the right info about the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't printing the  tag inside the PHP

```
    <?php do { ?>
     // div content //
     echo $row_post['title'];
     echo $row_post['date'];
     echo $row_post['category'];
     **echo '<img src="'.$row_post['avatar'].'"';**
    // end div content //
    <?php } while ($row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post)); ?>
```

EDIT.

You need to cross the tables with a JOIN, can you paste your SQL statement?

Comment: Thanks!! I read more about JOIN and now i solved the case. Thanks!!